# How do I write an external dialect for SQLAlchemy?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I wrote a minimal database dialect for SQLAlchemy that doesn't really belong in the core. How do I make it work as its own Python package?

Comment: I am interested in writing a minimal database dialect too - just for the purpose of mocking a real db. Can you please provide any pointers that can help?

Comment: @zzz777 database dialects translate SQLAlchemy commands into SQL that varies per database, like the difference between SELECT TOP 10 * FROM table or SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 10. Read the existing dialects if you want to make one. For example you would supply your databases' list of reserved words to the dialect.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) resolves a database url `example://...` it will first try to find it in `import sqlalchemy.dialects.example`. If that doesn't work it falls back to `pkg_resources.iter_entry_points('sqlachemy.databases')`.

Put the new dialect in a package using `setuptools`, include an entry point named after your dialect, run `python setup.py develop` or `python setup.py install`, and SQLAlchemy should be able to find the dialect.

In `setup.py`:

```
   entry_points = {
     'sqlalchemy.databases': ['example = example_sa:base.dialect',]
   },
```

`example_sa:base.dialect` means `import example_sa; return example_sa.base.dialect`.

After installing this package, `pkg_resources.iter_entry_points(group)` yields `pkg_resources.EntryPoint` instances from `group`. Call `.load()` on the `EntryPoint` with `entrypoint.name='example'` and you get `example_sa.base.dialect`.

I was pleasantly surprised at how easy it is to write new dialects for SQLAlchemy 0.6. If your database has just a few quirks compared to standard SQL, chances are you will be able to inherit from the standard (MySQL-like) SQL dialect, define your database's keywords, and copy the implementation of those quirks (like `SELECT TOP 10` instead of `SELECT ... LIMIT 10`) from an existing dialect.

Comment: In SQLAlchemy 0.5 the entry point is called sqlalchemy.databases

Answer (score 21):

As of SQLAlchemy 0.8, you can register the dialects in-process without needing to have a separate install.

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects import registry
registry.register("mysql.foodialect", "myapp.dialect", "MyMySQLDialect")
```

The above will respond to `create_engine("mysql+foodialect://")` and load the `MyMySQLDialect` class from the `myapp.dialect` module.

See: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#registering-new-dialects

Answer (score -1):

At least in SQLAlchemy 5.x you can just drop your driver/dialect in the databases directory, wherever that is on your system, (if you installed from source, it might be /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/SQLAlchemy-0.5.8-py2.7.egg/sqlalchemy/databases)